# Does XFCE have a sticky edges option or plugin?

Tags: multiple-monitors, xfce

I'm using two monitors and really enjoyed the sticky edges feature of GNOME.  Does XFCE have something similar?

Sticky edges, in Unity, meant that when moving the mouse between your two displays, it would stick to the edge of your current display initially, and if you kept moving it would finally pass the edge into the other display.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but try enabling "Window snapping", "To screen borders" or "To other windows" at:
**Settings Manager > Personal > Window Manager > Advanced > Window Snapping**.

OR

**Window Manager GUI > Advanced > Window Snapping**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I wasn't being very clear with my question.  I've updated it to indicate what I am referring to.

Comment: You see the image and **Wrap workspaces** check group

Comment: In XFCE terms it should be **Wrap + Snap**